# RegEx for match strings that doesn't start and/or end with a dot

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am trying to write a RegEx for get every string that doesn't start and/or end with a dot (`.`). [Here](https://regex101.com/r/bD2dR3/3) is the example I am working on but it doesn't work since nothing is a match.

```
// valid match would be
Alison
Alizon
Amada
Amanda
Ami

// not valid match wold be
Alison. // dot at end
Alizon. // dot at end
.Amada // dot at beggining
Amanda. // dot at end
Ami. // dot at end
.Ami. // dot at beggining and end
```

I have tried this other too: `^".*[^.]$` but doesn't work neither.

can any give me some help?

**Note:** I will use this in a MySQL query as for example: `SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE description REGEXP 'here_goes_the_RegEx'`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE description NOT LIKE '.%' AND NOT LIKE '%.'` Replace AND with OR depending on the logic.

Comment: Another case of trying to force a regular expression in where none is needed. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite yes, you're right I was taking the hard path one there is a easy one, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that without a regex:

```
SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE description NOT LIKE '.%' AND description NOT LIKE '%.'
```

Replace AND with OR depending on the logic.

Comment: It's been a while that I needed SQL, but wouldn't you need `description` also after the `AND`?

Comment: I am using MySQL from time to time at work, but can't remember exactly. I have checked some online resources and it is a good idea to remove any ambiguity from the query by adding the column name after the `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex:

```
(^((?!.).)*[a-z]+[\w]+((?!.).)*$)
```

For more Information refer this [Link](https://regex101.com/)